# Safari <body onload> event doesn't trigger from the back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, onload, back

I don't seem to be able to get the body onload="..." event to fire in Safari when the page is entered via the back button.  It works fine in FF and IE.  Is there a Javascript or jQuery solution?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: does it work in chrome ?

Comment: What does the code attached to the `onload` event do? Are you sure that the event isn't firing at all, or is it just not doing anything visible?

Comment: Jorge Pinho. I've not ried Chrome yet.  Still working through the browsers...

Comment: This is a known issue. The bright side is that Safari "caches" UI state like form element states.

Comment: Anthony.  It's refreshes the page depending a a flag value.  I've set an alert to see if it fires when the back button is used.  The alert comes up fine in FF and IE but not Safari.  Thus the refresh doesn't happen.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
window.addEventListener("pageshow", function() {
  alert('page shown');
}, false);
```

For **Opera** browser, read this: http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/onload-issues-with-opera/

Comment: Zvona, Ive treid this but nothing happens.  Is the code example good for a cut and paster into my site , i.e. does anything have to be changed?

Comment: It's good like that. I tested it with Chrome and it worked, don't know about Safari.

You can read this article, if it's any help: http://www.webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/

Comment: zvona, I've got pageshow to trigger in Safari and FF but not IE.  Do you know if it should work there too?  If it doesn't, how do I distinguish between browsers to avoid the doc.ready AND the pagshow calling the function twice?

Comment: @Mark_54 Something like:
if ("onpageshow" in window) { window.addEventListener("pageshow", [...], false); } else { window.addEventListener("load", [...], false); }

Comment: Actually, for (older) IE's, you might need window.attachEvent instead of addEventListener. Do some googling and you'll be fine (because this is a question inside a question :))

Answer (score 0):

This is well known. Safari and many other browser cache the page and when you navigate back to it, they just restore the previous state.

Here is a good MDN article about this topic (it's about FF 1.5 but should apply to other browsers as well): https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching

Try the `pageshow` event like @zvona suggested.

Comment: Hi Jan, I've got pageshow to trigger in Safari and FF but not IE. Do you know if it should work there too? If it doesn't, how do I distinguish between browsers to avoid the doc.ready AND the pagshow calling the function twice?

Answer (score 0):

if the onload event is not fired,you should set the cache-control.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

or add a  tag in the body:

```
<iframe style=”height:0px;width:0px;visibility:hidden” src=”about:blank”>
this frame prevents back forward cache
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the only thing that worked for me:

http://jkoder.com/prevent-safariany-browser-loading-from-cache-when-back-button-is-clicked/

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
  if (event.persisted) {
      window.location.reload(); 
  }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Rather than using the `onload` attribute of the `<body>` tag, you could instead try using the DOM ready event with jQuery, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Or, the shorthand version:

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Even if this doesn't solve your issue with Safari, it's still a good practice in general because it separates your HTML and Javascript into easily discernible parts.

Comment: Hi Anthony.  I've just tried this but it too only fires in FF and IE.