# not understood working js in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

If write this:

```
        $(document).on("click", function () {
             window.scroll( 0, 70 );
        });
```

works always, but if write this:

```
        window.onload = function () {
             window.scroll( 0, 70 );
        }
```

this not works  in safari and in "incognito window" for chrome. in other browsers works.
why?

Comment: take a look at answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/9227433/1499781

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In very simple terms, the main reason is the state of the different browser/dom elements you are binding to.

In the first one, you are binding to the `click` event on the `<body/>` using jQuery, which is possibly ensuring that by the time you get around to actually clicking it, the `body` of the document is initialised and has enough scroll left to make the effect appear to you.

In the second one, you are binding to the `onload` event of the window, which actually fires much before the `body` may have loaded, or accumulated enough scrollable area, thus making the effect to not appear.

The ideal technique instead would be to use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0,70);
});
```